# I'm trying to count the positive numbers and add the negative numbers

Tags: php

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives ($nums){
    $count = 0 ;
    $sum = 0 ; 
    $arcount = 0 ;
    if ($arcount === count($nums)){
        return [];
    }else {
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($nums) ; $i++){
            if ($nums[$i] > 0){
                $count++;
            }else{
                $sum +=$nums[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return [$count,$sum];
}
```

When I use the previous code in vscode it adds negative numbers and calculates positive numbers, but when I put the same code in codewars editor it returns error

> TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable |
> array , given null

Comment: The error seems to indicate that `$nums` is `null`.  Is it?  How is this function being invoked and what is being passed to it?

Comment: this function tests if the array given is null or not if it is null it should return empty array if it is not it returns the count of the positive numbers and the sum of the non-positive numbers , I want to know why i am seeing this error message  ? , it should return an empty array right?

Comment: No, `count()` only works on array (eventually empty), not on `null`.

Comment: @kerolossamy: *"this function tests if the array given is null or not if it is null it should return empty array"* - Where is the code shown doing that?  When you test this function by passing it a `null` value, what happens?  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you're observing and indicate specifically which operation isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: `this function tests if the array given is null or not if it is null it should return empty array if it is not it returns the count of the positive numbers and the sum of the non-positive numbers`....ok but that's not what you are being asked. If you have a problem with the `$sum` variable then you need to show how the function was called, including what was passed in for the `$sum`

Comment: function countPositivesSumNegatives ($nums){
 $count = 0 ;
 $sum = 0 ; 
 $arcount = 0 ;
 if ($arcount === count($nums)){
  return [];
 }else {
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($nums) ; $i++){
   if ($nums[$i] > 0){
    $count++;
   }else{
    $sum +=$nums[$i];
   }
  }
 }
 return [$count,$sum];
}
print_r(countPositivesSumNegatives([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]));
print_r(countPositivesSumNegatives([]));

Comment: @kerolossamy: Relevant code belongs in the question, not in comments.  Code in comments is barely readable.

Comment: Well that code doesn't produce the error you're claiming in the question - demo: https://3v4l.org/YOkJ2. To tell you what the problem is, we would need a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask].

Answer (score 3):

How do you call your function ?

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives ($nums){
    $count = 0 ;
    $sum = 0 ; 
    if (!is_array($nums) || empty($nums)){
        return [];
    }else {
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($nums) ; $i++){
            if ($nums[$i] > 0){
                $count++;
            }else{
                $sum +=$nums[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return [$count,$sum];
}


countPositivesSumNegatives([2,3,4]);
```

To use "count", you need to pass an array, not values separated by comma.

You can use this one too :

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives (...$nums){
    $count = 0 ;
    $sum = 0 ;
    if (empty($nums)){
        return [];
    }else {
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($nums) ; $i++){
            if ($nums[$i] > 0){
                $count++;
            }else{
                $sum +=$nums[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return [$count,$sum];
}


countPositivesSumNegatives(2,3,4);
```

Regards,

Comment: i did pass an array and this is the code   function countPositivesSumNegatives ($nums){
 $count = 0 ;
 $sum = 0 ; 
 $arcount = 0 ;
 if ($arcount === count($nums)){
  return [];
 }else {
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($nums) ; $i++){
   if ($nums[$i] > 0){
    $count++;
   }else{
    $sum +=$nums[$i];
   }
  }
 }
 return [$count,$sum];
}
print_r(countPositivesSumNegatives([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]));
print_r(countPositivesSumNegatives([]));

Comment: Could you please try my solutions and let me know.

Comment: this was helpful thank you man the issue was in this three dots in the first line

Comment: how can i do this

Comment: just click on the check mark under my 3 likes answers

Comment: man i didn't find the check mark i'm sorry :(  if you can explain more i'm  going to do it    right a way :)